# The strictest isInt() function that will detect 2.00 as float, not integer

Tags: javascript, regex

We want `isInt(1.00000)` return false. We want 1.000 detected as float, not int. Is this still possible?

Many peoples have created `isInt()` function. But they always detect `1.0` or just `1.0000` as integer, not float. When we input `1.01` their isInt() success return false. But it fails on `1.00` or more of 0 :D
How to solve this? **Or just no way**?

```
function isInt(i) {
    if ( i.toFixed ) {
        if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

as other functions, it success return false on 1.03 but fails on 1.00000 and more 0. 
my plan:

```
function isInt(i) {
    if ( i.toFixed ) {
        if ( i % 1 === 0 ) {
            /** the plan, but sure, it fails
            i = i.toString().split('.');
            if ( i.length > 1 ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            **/
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code works: http://jsfiddle.net/GWEwE/

Comment: @ComFreek I think the OP expects `1.00000` to be a "float"...yet your code (and the OP's) shows that it's an int. But it doesn't matter, because `1.0000 === 1` - JavaScript doesn't have number types

Comment: Do you plan to run this against strings, or numbers? As @Ian says, the numeric literals `1.0` and `1` are indistinguishable to executing code; they map to identical values. Indeed, all numbers in JavaScript are stored as floating point values, so `1` is -- internally speaking -- also a float.

Comment: @ComFreek , yes, my wishlist, 1.000000 can be detected as float with our own function

Comment: To explain it another way: all numbers in JS are stored as floating point values. A floating point value is a *base* (or "mantissa") multiplied by 2 to some *exponent*. So, when `1` is parsed or `1.000` is parsed, they both turn into a value expressed by `1 * 2^0`, and the original literal used to create the value is lost.

Comment: isnt 1.0 techincally an INT anyway? its just displayed in a float format.

Comment: the first `isInt` implementation you posted works as expected... The rest of the regex or split-on-dot examples will fail with things like `1.0`, `3e1` or `2.2e3`, which are all integers.

Comment: @mamápitufo , no it is not expected. because `isInt(1.000)` returns `true` . We want it returns `false` . Because we want 1.000 detected as float

Comment: @SlametBedjo yeah, I didn't understand that requirement from the original question, sorry. apsillers answer actually explains why it's not possible to do what you want, or how to change your function to do what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you -- a human -- want to express a value in a program, you use a **number literal**, like `1`, or `2.34`, or `9999`.

When a JavaScript interpreter reads numeric literals, it immediately turns them into floating point representations and forgets the original literal you used. A floating point value is an integer *base* (or "*mantissa*") multiplied by 2 raised to some integer *exponent*: `m * 2^e`. Therefore, when you use the literal `1`, JavaScript internally remembers `1 * 2^0`. When `1.000` is parsed, JS again remembers only `1 * 2^0`.

You are passing the floating-point value `1 * 2^0` to a function and you expect it to make a decision based on the original literal that created that value. That's not possible, because (as I explained above) numeric literal values are immediately forgotten once they are parsed.

**Instead**, you must pass the function a *string*, whose original literal formulation will not be forgotten by the interpreter. You might be tempted to do something like this:

```
var myStringValue = (1.000).toString();
```

But that won't work. In order to evaluate the expression `(1.000).toString()`, JavaScript first must parse the numeric literal `1.000`, which turns to `1 * 2^0`. That floating point value is then converted by `toString` into the string "`1`". `toString` only has access to the floating point representation, not your original literal.

Comment: Alright, we got the conclusion. Safe to say that **It always impossible** to make isInt(1.000) to returns `false` Thank you very much

Answer (score -2):

you could use regex

```
function isInt(value){
    if( String(value).search(/^-?\d+$/) != -1 ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work because a `Number` object doesn't have the method `search`.

Comment: This won't work either (I've already tried it) because the string conversion will for example convert `1.0` to `1`.

Comment: thank you @milkshake . But this still detect 1.0 as integer. we want isInt(1.0) returns false :) because we want 1.0 is float

Answer (score -3):

```
function isInt(i){
    return String(i).match(/^\d*$/) != null;
}
```

This will return false if the input consists of anything but numbers..

```
isInt(123) --> true
isInt('a') --> false
isInt(123.1) --> false
```

Comment: `1.00 === 1 && String(1.00) === '1'`

Comment: @thor-jacobsen : again, it fails on 1.000 . the wish is, 1.00 detected as float. we want it return false. but on your code, my code, and others code, isInt(1.00) return true. we want it returns false